# SQL Query error when extending JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have the following ItemReader class

```
 @Configuration
    public class ReadingObjectItemReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> {

        public DataSource getDataSource() { return dataSource; }        
        @Resource
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) { super.setDataSource(dataSource); }

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> cursorReader() {
            JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
            databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            databaseReader.setSql("select TOP(10) * from dbo.Person ");
            databaseReader.setFetchSize(5);
            databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
            return databaseReader;
        }
}
```

when I am running my code base which has the above code as itemReader I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The SQL query must be provided
```

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readingObjectItemReader' defined in file [\demo-project\bin\main\com\spring-batch\test\config\ReadingObjectItemReader.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The SQL query must be provided
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.CcrsPitextractApplication.main(CcrsPitextractApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The SQL query must be provided
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:108) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.config.ReadingObjectItemReader.afterPropertiesSet(ReadingObjectItemReader.java:58) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Is there anything that I should be adding for this code to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i always saw the `TOP` clause without brackets. Did you try to write the query like this `select TOP 10 * from dbo.Person`

Comment: @Angelo Immediata Yes I did try that as well. Also, for simplicity sake I did try `select person_id, person_name from dbo.Person` but still getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The SQL query must be provided`

Comment: may you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @Angelo Immediata I have edited the post with the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by not extending the JdbcCursorItemReader and passing the datasource from class where I have defined my step.

After making the corrections the class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ReadingObjectItemReader {

    @Bean
    ItemReader<Person> cursorReaderForDb(DataSource dataSource) {
        String sql = "select TOP(10) * from dbo.Person ";
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> cursor = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Person>();
        cursor.setDataSource(dataSource);
        cursor.setSql(sql);
        cursor.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
        cursor.setFetchSize(10);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

I am aware that this is a strange behavior. I still wanted to get this working by extending JdbcCursorItemReader. So, any suggestions to make it correct is appreciated.